# jQuery - submit a form with an anchor

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

I want to submit a form with an anchor instead of a button.
Here is my html code for the form:

```html
<form id="subscribe" action="index.html" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><a class="sendmail">Subscribe</a>
</form>
```

Using this jQuery works fine:

```js
$('.sendmail').click(function() {
    $('#subscribe').submit();
});
```

But I want to verify the input field, so I added this to my jQuery code:

```js
$('.sendmail').click(function() {       
$('#subscribe').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if ($('#email').val() == "") {
        $('.falsification').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    else {          
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: "email="+ $('#email').val(),
        success: function() {
            $('.falsification').hide();
            $('#subscribe').hide();
            $('.verification').fadeIn(1000);}
    });         
    }               
}); 
});
```

But this doesn't work. Do you have any conclusion?

Comment: Sometimes people style a button to look like an anchor instead of the other way around.

Comment: View Source [here](http://www.beginningjavascript.com/Chapter4/exampleSubmitToLinks.html) to make a submit button look like an anchor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your .sendmail click handler, you set the submit handler for the form but don't actually submit it. Try moving that code `$('#subscribe').submit(function(e){ ...` outside of the click handler and use the original handler you posted `$('#subscribe').submit();`

EDIT:
In other words...

```
$('#subscribe').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if ($('#email').val() == "") {
        $('.falsification').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    else {          
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: "email="+ $('#email').val(),
        success: function() {
            $('.falsification').hide();
            $('#subscribe').hide();
            $('.verification').fadeIn(1000);}
    });         
    }               
});

$('.sendmail').click(function() {       
    $('#subscribe').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//bind click event handler to link
$('.sendmail').click(function () {

    //find the form that this link is in and trigger a submit event for the form
    $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');

    //return false to stop the default behavior of the link
    return false;
});
```

This will work for all `.sendmail` elements that are descendants of a `form` element. `.closest()` finds the first element that is a direct ancestor to the root element that matches the selector (in this case `form`).

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4hsPE/

It appears as though your `form.submit` event handler is nested within the `click` event handler for the link. The `form.submit` event handler should be in the same scope as the `click` event handler for the link:

```
$('.sendmail').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
    return false;
});   

$('#subscribe').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if ($('#email').val() == "") {
        $('.falsification').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    else {          
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: "email="+ $('#email').val(),
        success: function() {
            $('.falsification').hide();
            $('#subscribe').hide();
            $('.verification').fadeIn(1000);}
    });         
    }               
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to seperate them:

```
$('.sendmail').click(function() {
    $('#subscribe').submit();
});

$('#subscribe').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if ($('#email').val() == "") {
        $('.falsification').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    else {          
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: "email="+ $('#email').val(),
        success: function() {
            $('.falsification').hide();
            $('#subscribe').hide();
            $('.verification').fadeIn(1000);}
    });         
    }
});
```